# How does Restful WS works with multiple clients at the same time?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am new to the RESTful Webservices world and I have a question regarding how WS works.

Context:

I am developing a RESTful WS that will have a high load; at one given time I can have let's say up to 10 clients sending multiple requests. All the requests will be sent to port 80.

I am developing the WS with Jersey (Java) and deploying on a Tomcat Webserver.

Question:

Let's say we have 5 clients that send requests at the same time; each one sends 2 requests to port 80; will they be treated in FIFO order? Can we have some sort of multi-threading if let's say we don't care about the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends what server you use and how it is configured. Standard configuration (you have to work hard to make it not standard) is to have multiple threads. In other words - server usually automatically creates or uses another thread for each new request and it is almost certain that it will be processed in parallel.

You can actually see it inside your running code by using java.lang.Thread.currentThread() - print the name of current thread and Rest request and you will see.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, a thread will be fetched from thread pool to server every request you send. The server does not care about the order, the request comes first will be served first.

More about the servers:
I suggest you use Nginx or Apache as reverse server to enable high performance, a thread will be fetched from the thread pool to server the request. To improve performance, you can increase the thread pool size. However, too much thread will, on the other hand, reduce your performance due to the frequency of switching from thread to thread increases. You don't want to have a very large thread pool.

If you are using Apache + Tomcat, basically, you have the same situation like you are using Tomcat. But apache is more suitable than tomcat to be the web server. In real life, companies use apache as reverse server that dispatch request to tomcat.

Apache and Tomcat are multithread based server, their performance reduce when there are too much requests. If you have to handle a lot of requests, you can use Nginx.

Nginx is an even based server, it uses queue to store requests and use FIFO to dispatch them. It can handle a lot of requests with much fewer threads. Therefore, its performance will be more stable even with larger amount of requests. However, with extremely large amount of requests, Nginx will also be overwhelmed, as its event loop has no room for extra requests.

Companies due with the situation by using distributed system concepts. For example load balancer. But to answer your question, that's a little too much. Check [this article](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-vs-apache-our-view/) and [this article](https://anturis.com/blog/nginx-vs-apache/) to gain a better idea about nginx and apache.